# Deleting smart pointers containing STL containers containing dynamic objects

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers

If you have a smart pointer to an STL container that contains raw pointers that are managed somewhere else, will the raw pointers be deleted when the smart pointer deallocates the container?

For context, I'm writing a collision detection system for a game that needs to store a temporary list of pairs of game entities that are colliding with each other at any given time, and to me it makes the most sense to store this list as

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<std::array<gameEntity *, 2>>, SOME_LARGE_NUMBER>
```

so that the sub-arrays containing the pairs can be allocated and deallocated as needed. That being said, the gameEntity pointers are being managed in a central list elsewhere in the program, and it would be disastrous if the unique_ptr deallocated the contents of the array along with the array. My understanding from other sources is that smart pointers aren't necessary when managing the lifetime of the object isn't a concern, which is why I'm just using raw pointers here, along with the fact that shared_ptrs would add unnecessary overhead, this being inside a hot code path in a performance-critical application.

So my question is, will the raw pointers inside the array get deallocated when the smart pointer deallocates the array?

EDIT: It might not be a hot code path, depending on your definition; typical usage would see anywhere from 10-100 of these array allocations made every frame, which is 1/30 or 1/60 of a second depending on the situation, and I don't know if that would qualify or not. In any case, though, it's still a performance-intensive application as a whole.

Comment: It makes no difference if a smart pointer is managing the lifetime of an object.

Comment: Working backward:  if there is a set of raw pointers in a container that are all "managed somewhere else", then destroying the container does not release those pointers.   A smart pointer that manages lifetime of a dynamically created container will only destroy that container, so the "raw pointers" will never be released.

Comment: Also there is usually no need to have a smart pointer to a container (unless it needs shared ownership).

Comment: Also allocating/deallocating memory is slow. Your array structure contains one pointer instead of two pointers (saving a some space when "empty" but increasing space when "full") but at the expense of two indirections per access which is slower (in addition to time needed to allocate/deallocate).

Comment: @Galik Thanks for mentioning the lack of need for a smart pointer. That hadn't occured to me. Also, the slowness of allocation/deallocation and indirection isn't lost on me, but as far as I'm aware there isn't any other feasible way to do it in this context, since new entities are being created and destroyed all the time, and interfaces (i.e. polymorphism) are all but unavoidable too. At least, this is how it's done in all of the examples I've seen, since I don't have the experience yet to be able to unquestionably say that that's the way it is.

Comment: You could do: `std::array<std::array<gameEntity *, 2>, SOME_LARGE_NUMBER>` and still have your polymorphism. That would reduce the number of allocations and the redirections.

Comment: In that situation, the outer array would be fully populated with blank entries from the beginning, right? So it would be a tradeoff between efficiency and memory usage.

Not that pointers take up very much memory to begin with.

Comment: Which, I see after having posted that, is what you were getting at in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**. Deallocating a raw pointer (whether in a container or not) never deletes the thing it points to. You have to do that explicitly using `delete` or get a *smart pointer* to do it for you, or have it go out of scope.

For example:

```
auto arr_ptr = std::make_unique<std::array<int*, 2>>();
(*arr_ptr)[0] = new int(5);
(*arr_ptr)[1] = new int(9);

arr_ptr.reset(); // this is a memory leak!!
```

Comment: I think I got the terminology wrong. By "deallocate," I meant delete. I guess that makes my question whether the deletion of the array by the smart pointer will also delete the pointers inside it.

Comment: @Jarius Terminology is difficult here because it can be hard to differentiate between deleting the pointer itself and deleting the thing the pointer points to. Just saying "delete the pointer" usually means the thing it points to but technically can also mean the pointer object itself. Which is why I kept "deallocate" when referring to the pointer itself.